# Unknown 'notify' folders randomly generated

Tags: windows

I can't figure out why some folders named 'notify'+'*a random number*' are generated in my Local Disk D. They're empty and there are no hidden folders/files inside. Also, they regenerate if I delete them and restart the computer. They look like this:

[image: image #1]

I have no idea what could have generated them now nor in the past. I learned that explorer.exe (apparently) does this. Maybe this helps : http://pastebin.com/raw/TZcsrjWK (by the time I used a software to get this info, another folder was created).

Does anyone have any idea what those mean and what's their purpose? How can I get rid of them?

Comment: Are you using CrashPlan by any chance?

Comment: Actually, yes. I am.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's being created by CrashPlan, or at least CrashPlan is conflicting with something that's causing them to be created (and not cleaned up properly).

> Glad someone else has come across this issue.  I've narrowed it down to CrashPlan.

...

> I stopped CrashPlanTray.exe & CrashPlanService.exe in C:\Program Files\CrashPlan from starting up and the folders no longer appear when and I reboot.  I emailed CrashPlan's tech support team and they claimed that CrashPlan does not make any changes outside of it's main directory, and that something else is conflicting with the program and causing these folders.

This quote [was posted Jan. 18, 2016](http://www.bleepingcomputer.com/forums/t/601681/empty-unknown-notify-folders-are-being-created-upon-shutdown/), so this may be a newer problem, that CrashPlan hadn't recognized at the time.

You should [contact their support](https://support.code42.com/Support).

Comment: Will do! Thank you for clarifying this, at least now I know the source.